# Return anti-join of two data frames with values outside a certain percentage difference

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, fuzzyjoin, anti-join

I would like to compare two mixed-type data frames and return the rows that are different between them--but I would like numeric values to only be returned within a certain percentage.

```
tbl1 <- tibble(var1 = c('r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5'),
               var2 = c('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry', 'lime'),
               var3 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               var4 = c('yes', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'))

tbl2 <- tibble(var1 = c('r6', 'r7', 'r8', 'r9', 'r10'),
               var2 = c('orange', 'banana', 'apple', 'lemon', 'strawberry'),
               var3 = c(2, 3, 1.5, 10, 4.1),
               var4 = c('no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'yes'))
```

I know there is `dplyr::anti_join` but that checks for exact matches. So if I was OK with numeric values that were within 20%, then the function would be something like:

```
tbl1 %>%
  antijoin_function(tbl2, by = c('var2' = 'var2', 'var3' = 'var3', 'var4' = 'var4'),
                    pct = 0.2)
```

And return

| var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | apple | 1 | yes |
| r5 | lime | 5 | no |

The row with `strawberry` would not be returned because the single difference in `var3` is less than 20%.

Are there any functions or packages that do this?

Comment: Let's take first row of `tbl1` as an example. You want to match that with the third row of `tbl2` and if `var3` difference is greater than 20%, then you'll keep it, otherwise your drop it. Did I get that right?

Comment: Moreover, fuzzyjoin::difference_anti_join does exist, but it doesn't seem to be what you need based on your desired output. You are actually matching `var2` and then if the `var3` difference is more than 20% or if there is no match, you keep the rows from `tbl1`. There isn't a function that can do that at once. You need to tackle this in couple of steps.

Comment: The join needs to happen across multiple columns--i.e. for var2, var3, and var4 in tbl1, return the rows that don't match with ALL those values in tbl2, with the numeric ones counting as "matching" if they're within 20% or less.

Comment: i.e. char/factor columns should match exactly, numeric ones match within 20%. I need to make sure the match is along var4, as well. I created the dummy "var1" column because it DOESN'T need to match along var1, I just wanted to demonstrate that I couldn't anti-join along everything.

Comment: Finally, you want the rows for Character columns that match and have numeric columns with a difference of more than 20%, right? My answer below does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

full_join(tbl1, tbl2, by = c("var2" = "var2"), suffix = c("", ".right")) %>% 
  filter(abs(var3 - var3.right)/var3 > 0.2 | if_all(contains(".right"), ~ is.na(.))) %>% 
  select(-contains(".right"))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   var1  var2   var3 var4 
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 r1    apple     1 yes  
#> 2 r5    lime      5 no
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This seems to be neat.  Probably, they may extend the x$, y$ to other expressions.  Currently, in `?join_by`, - `Other expressions are not supported. If you need to perform a join on a computed variable, e.g. join_by(sales_date - 40 >= promo_date), you'll need to precompute and store it in a separate column.`